# Происходит однократная смена стиля элемента JS

Tags: javascript, css

пытаюсь реализовать примитивный слайдер, который состоит из картинок и переключателей, но появилась задача, что функция `Slider_AngleRight()` и `Slider_AngleLeft()` выполняется однократно. То есть, если вызвалась первая функция, то она поменяла стиль элемента и все, после этого смена стилей словно блокируется. При повторном вызове функции или вызове второй - нечего не происходит, но функция выполняется (проверка происходила через логи). Чтобы было более понятно смоделируем ситуация:
Я пытаюсь перелистнуть слайды вперед, то логи дадут следующее:

```
*Angle right*
slider.js:8 Now position: 
slider.js:10 margin-left: -440px
slider.js:11 ---------------------------------------
```

В итоге слайд переместится на 440px, теперь попробуем вернуть слайдер в первоначальное положение и вызовем функцию `Slider_AngleLeft()`, тогда консоль выведет следующий результат:

```
slider.js:19 *Angle left*
slider.js:22 Now position: -440px
slider.js:24 margin-left: 440px
```

Вроде все хорошо работает, но тут и начинаются танцы с бубном, теперь невозможно перемещать слайды, чтобы пользователь не тыкал, но сама функция вызывается, однако новый стиль отвергается, логи в студию:

```
slider.js:5 *Angle right*
slider.js:8 Now position: 440px
slider.js:10 margin-left: 440px
slider.js:11 ---------------------------------------
```

HTML

```
<!-- Open container order -->
<div class="container-order">
  <div class="Layout_Center">
    <p class="title"><i class="fa fa-diamond title-icon-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>Наши заказы</p>
    <div class="slider-my-order">
      <div class="left-gradient-slider"></div>
      <div id="slides">
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/2.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
        <img src="./img/slider/1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="right-gradient-slider"></div>
      <div class="control-slider">
        <a onclick="Slider_AngleLeft()">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left angle-slider" id="slider-return-slide" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <!-- Start point -->
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-circle circle-slider-activ" aria-hidden="true" onclick=""></i>
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" onclick=""></i>
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" onclick=""></i>
        </span>
        <!-- End point -->
        <a onclick="Slider_AngleRight()">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right angle-slider" id="slider-next-slide" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">Показать еще...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Close container order -->
```

Css slider

```
@import url(./style.css);
.slider-my-order {
    position: relative;
    margin: 82px 0 0 0;
    width: 974px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*900 X 280*/
}

.left-gradient-slider {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent, #f1f2f6);
}

.left-gradient-slider,
.right-gradient-slider {
    width: 35px;
    height: 280px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.right-gradient-slider {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #f1f2f6);
    top: 0;
    left: 939px;
}

#slides {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 37px;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

#slides>img {
    width: 405px;
    height: 273px;
    border: 3px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 9px #000000;
    margin: 0px 77px 0px 0px;
}

.control-slider {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.angle-slider {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: var(--companion-color);
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control-slider>span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--companion-color-light);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.control-slider>span>i {
    margin-left: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control-slider>span>i:hover {
    color: var(--main-color-light);
}

.control-slider>a {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    color: var(--companion-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.circle-slider-activ {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

#slider-next-slide {
    margin: 0px -7px 0px;
}

#slider-next-slide,
#slider-return-slide {
    color: var(--companion-color);
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

#slider-next-slide:hover,
#slider-return-slide:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Css style

```
.Layout_Center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1600px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.container-order {
    background-color: #f1f2f6;
}
.title-icon-color {
    color: var(--main-color);
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
function Slider_AngleRight() {
    // Первый отступ 37px
    // Высота картинки 237px
    // Ширина картинки 405px
    console.log("*Angle right*");
    var slides = document.getElementById("slides");
    var now_position_slides = slides.style.marginLeft;
    console.log("Now position: " + now_position_slides);
    slides.style.marginLeft = now_position_slides - 440 + "px";
    console.log("margin-left: " + slides.style.marginLeft);
    console.log("---------------------------------------");
}

function Slider_AngleLeft() {
    // Первый отступ 37px
    // Высота картинки 237px
    // Ширина картинки 405px

    console.log("*Angle left*");
    var slides = document.getElementById("slides");
    var now_position_slides = slides.style.marginLeft;
    console.log("Now position: " + now_position_slides);
    slides.style.marginLeft = now_position_slides + 440 + "px";
    console.log("margin-left: " + slides.style.marginLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот тут:

```
function Slider_AngleRight() {
    var slides = document.getElementById("slides");
    var now_position_slides = slides.style.marginLeft;

    slides.style.marginLeft = now_position_slides - 440 + "px";
```

Вы адресуетесь к слайдеру slides и пытаетесь его "переместить", обычно слайдер (родитель) неподвижный элемент а перемещают сами картинки внутри.
например:

JS

```
let currentPictureNumber = 0;
const slides = Array.from(document.getElementById("slides").children);
function sliderAngleRight(currentPictureNumber = 0) {

    slides.map(pic => pic.style.marginLeft = -9999 + "px" );
    currentPictureNumber++;
    if (currentPictureNumber > (slides.length -1)) {
      currentPictureNumber = (slides.length -1)
    }
    slides[currentPictureNumber].style.marginLeft = -440 + "px";
   }
(onClick) = sliderAngleRight(currentPictureNumber);
```

CSS

```
#slides {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
...
}

#slides > img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 405px;
    height: 273px;
...
}
```